# finitely generated projective module $\iff$ dual basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module, dual-spaces

I would like to prove the following result:

Given a right $R$-module $A_R$, it is a finitely generated projective module if and only if there exists a dual basis.

What could get me started?

Comment: Finitely generated projective module should be a direct summand of a f.g. free module. It is equivalent to prove that dual basis iff it provides you a retraction map from projective module to some finitely generated free module.